# Implementing a class property that preserves the docstring

Tags: python, properties, decorator, python-decorators, docstring

I have a descriptor that turns a method into a property on the class level:

```
class classproperty(object):

    def __init__(self, getter):
        self.getter = getter
        self.__doc__ = getter.__doc__

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.getter(owner)
```

Used like this:

```
class A(object):
    @classproperty
    def test(cls):
        "docstring"
        return "Test"
```

However, I now can't access the `__doc__` attribute (which is logical, because accessing `A.test.__doc__` will fetch the `__doc__` of `str`, because `A.test` already returns `"Test"`.

My final goal is that my docstring will appear in sphinx, so it is not feasible to retrieve the docstring in any other way than by accessing the attributes `__doc__` property. I find myself wondering if this is even possible in any way.

I know that `property` solves this issue by returning the class if called without an instance. However, it should be obvious that this collides with my goal.

I am starting to fear that this is not possible in Python.

*Note*: I am willing to pull any stunt in `classproperty` as long as it is stable (i.e. not setting `__doc__` on the returned value). However, it is not feasible to put any burden on the user of `classproperty` (i.e. they should only use the decorator and be done with it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, `test` is a property returning a string. You'd have to *subclass* `str` and give that a `__doc__` attribute:

```
class docstring_str(str):
    def __new__(cls, v, __doc__=''):
        s = super(docstring_str, cls).__new__(cls, v)
        s.__doc__ = __doc__
        return s
```

Demo:

```
>>> class docstring_str(str):
...     def __new__(cls, v, __doc__=''):
...         s = super(docstring_str, cls).__new__(cls, v)
...         s.__doc__ = __doc__
...         return s
... 
>>> s = docstring_str('Test', 'docstring')
>>> s
'Test'
>>> s.__doc__
'docstring'
```

Use as:

```
class A(object):
    @classproperty
    def test(cls):
        return docstring_str("Test", "docstring')
```

Because `str` objects are immutable, you **cannot** set the `__doc__` attribute in a decorator. You'd have to return a proxy object instead that fully wraps the actual return value except for the `__doc__` attribute. This gets to be complex and ugly fast.

The alternative is to put a regular `property` *on the metaclass*; the class's class:

```
class MetaClass(type):
    @property
    def test(cls):
        "docstring"
        return "Test"

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass
```

Now `A` has a `test` property, and the docstring can be accessed as `MetaClass.test.__doc__` or with `type(A).test.__doc__`:

```
>>> A.test
'Test'
>>> type(A).test
<property object at 0x10757d158>
>>> type(A).test.__doc__
'docstring'
```

Comment: Ooo... property on a metaclass (*makes mental note*)

Comment: Hmmm, it seems between this and the answer below, there are two solutions: One puts extra work on the user (i.e. no easy `@classproperty`) and the other does not provide a direct `__doc__`). I think I'll go with the metaclass way then. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you jump through a few hoops, it can be retrieved, but not directly through the property itself like `A.test.__doc__` because of the way descriptors work.

```
class classproperty(object):
    def __init__(self, getter):
        self.getter = getter

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:  # instance attribute accessed on class?
            return self
        return self.getter(owner)

class A(object):
    @classproperty
    def test(cls):
        "test's docstring"
        return "Test"

def docstring(cls, methodname):
    return getattr(cls, methodname).getter.__doc__

print docstring(A, 'test')  # -> test's docstring
```