# Idiom to define a class property

Tags: python, properties, idioms

To define a property, we can use

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(f):
        self._f = f

    def custom_function(self):
        self._f += 1

    @property
    def f(self):
        return self._f
```

such that

```
>>x = MyClass(1)
>>print(x.f)  # prints 2
```

---

Is there any standard way to define the interface

```
>>MyClass.f  # <- calls custom classmethod
```

? I.e. a "`@classproperty`".

I'm aware of `@classmethod` but I don't want the interface to have the call `()`.

Comment: Closely related: [Implementing a class property that preserves the docstring](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22357961), and also [Python, how does the @property decorator work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17330160) (for the details on how a property resolves).

Comment: Your options are to use a regular `@property` on a method on the *metaclass*, or to create a custom descriptor that handles access on the class.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, `@property` on the meta! That's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: Put a property on the *metaclass*, or create a [custom descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) to translate a `.__get__` directly into a function call, regardless of the context; the `property` descriptor only does this when there is an instance, returning `self` for when accessed on the class.

Metaclass:

```
class MetaClass(type):
    @property
    def f(cls):
        return cls._f

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass

    def __init__(f):
        self._f = f
```

Custom descriptor:

```
class classproperty(object):
    def __init__(self, getter):
        self.getter = getter

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return self.getter(cls)

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(f):
        self._f = f

    @classproperty
    def f(cls):
        return cls._f
```

Be aware that there are [limitations to the latter approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357961/implementing-a-class-property-that-preserves-the-docstring).

Comment: I was using a metaclass anyway so the former fits just right. :) Thanks a lot.